# How do I use the Java Script JSON.parse() function exactely to display the text flat?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I tried using the parse function but it quite didn't work the way I wanted it to work. This is my code to load a .json file and print it into the terminal.

```
const fs = require('fs')

function loadJSON(filename = ''){
    return JSON.parse(
        fs.existsSync(filename)
            ? fs.readFileSync(filename)
            : '""'
    )
}

data = loadJSON('test.json')
console.log(data)
```

But the output in the console was:

```
{
  name: 'Frederik Message File',
  Version: 'Frederik Support Asisstant',
  messages: {
    '21.01.2021': { name: 'Frederik', message: "I don't know what to say..." },
    '22.01.2021': { name: 'Frederik', message: 'What am I supposed to do?' }   
  }
}
```

But I wanted it all to be on the same line, is that even possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This isn't JSON (a string) that you're printing, it's a JS object after you parse it. The `console.log` just pretty-prints it.

Answer (score 1):

When you log an object or array, the console may well try to pretty it up - and, for example, display key-value pairs on separate lines. If you want to display it all on one line, and the source file has the text all on one line, then just don't `JSON.parse` it, and display the *plain text*:

```
function loadJSON(filename = ''){
    return fs.existsSync(filename)
        ? fs.readFileSync(filename)
        : '""'
}
```

If the source file has the text spread out over multiple lines, you can parse it into an object, then turn it back into a string without extra spacing:

```
function loadJSON(filename = ''){
    return JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(
        fs.existsSync(filename)
            ? fs.readFileSync(filename)
            : '""'
    ));
}
```

Comment: The thing is that the text is not displayed in one line in the source file.

Comment: You can parse then stringify to remove the spacing.